# Get the text from multiple elements with the same class in Selenium for Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape data from a page with JavaScript loaded content. For example, the content I want is in the following format:

```
<span class="class">text</span>
...
<span class="class">more text</span>
```

I used the `find_element_by_xpath(//span[@class="class"]').text` function but it only returned the first instance of the specified class. Basically, I would want a list like `[text, more text]` etc. I found the `find_elements_by_xpath()` function, but the `.text` at the end results in an error `exceptions.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`find_element_by_xpath` returns one element, which has `text` attribute.

`find_elements_by_xpath()` returns all matching elements, which is a list, so you need to loop through and get `text` attribute for each of the element.

```
all_spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='class']")
for span in all_spans:
    print span.text
```

Please refer to Selenium Python API docs [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py) for more details about `find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)`.

Answer (score 6):

This returns a list of items:

```
all_spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='class']")
for span in all_spans:
    print span.text
```