# Selenium IDE, selecting muliple text using same class

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a page with lots of text using the same class. I am wanting to select and store all the text with that same class. Is this possible? All advice & comments appreciated!

I have HTML code like this:

```
<p class="foo">Some sample text</p>
<p class="foo">Some more sample text</p>
```

I have tried this:

```
<tr>
<td>storeText</td>
<td>//p[@class=foo']</td>
<td>var1</td>
</tr>
```

I expected var1 to be:

```
Some sample text
Some more sample text
```

Alternatively do I need to set up a while statement and gather each individually?

This page talks about a similar exercise, but uses Selenium for Python: [Get the text from multiple elements with the same class in Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924008/how-do-i-get-the-text-from-multiple-web-elements-with-the-same-class-using-selen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get to try out the answer from @bcar because I am not a javascript expert nor am I sure I could put the answer into IDE. I found another way however. I discovered that the text is stored in tables, so I am using the following code to extract the entire table (which includes the text I need).

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//div/h2[text()=&quot;Elements and Performance Criteria&quot;]/following::table</td>
    <td>Content</td>
</tr>
```

Now I have to work out how to replace the new lines with 
 as this is plain text. Another question for stackoverflow! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
//gather all p[class=foo]
List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("p.foo"));

Iterator<WebElement> iter = ele.iterator();

// initialize array, map, whatever

While(iter.hasNext()) {
    // insert text into map
    // print to log
   // store in array
   //whatever you need
   var.add( iter.next().text() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bcar, is this for Selenium Webdriver rather than IDE? I'd like to do this within IDE, I don't think your code is javacript with I could run using runScript.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy:
Just loop through the stored elements.
Whenever you use `find_elements_by_class_name`, it returns the list of selenium web elements. Hence you just need to iterate with a loop, like this.

```
names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_xEcR")
for i in names:
    print(i.text)
```