# Selenium python trouble finding element

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

[image]

Im trying to access the highlighted image but am having trouble I have tried the XPATH and CSS SELECTOR but neither seem to be working. Using Selenium w python & chrome btw

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(cwd+'/chromedriver')
driver.get('site_url')     
all_spans=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='Practice_Question_Body']")
for span in all_spans:
    textHtml =span.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

## cwd is your directory(obviously i don't know where chromedriver is)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/110682163d9048bd64c1f8fb346a447d Im getting this error

Comment: not working unfortunately, I dont understand keeps giving me no element exception when it should work

Comment: if you pass me the link of the site I can find the problem faster

Comment: I believe you can solve this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924008/get-the-text-from-multiple-elements-with-the-same-class-in-selenium-for-python)

Comment: The link of the site is edgenuity, which is for online school work so i dont believe youll be able to access it

Answer (score 1):

Try below xpath :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element =wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Practice_Question_Body'][contains(.,'What is the purpose of')]")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: No it is not working getting this error [code]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Practice_Question_Body'][contains(.,'What is the purpose of'")))
  File "C:\Users\Dillionb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: [/code]