# webscraping selenium : my loop always get only the 1st element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping

Im trying to scrap this website : http://scrumquiz.org/#/scrum-master-practice-test

I want in the end to get all the questions/answers and correct answers
So here's my code which will get me to the end of the quizz with all the Q/A and correct answers

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#import time
import json
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Ihnhn/Documents/WebScrap/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://scrumquiz.org/#/scrum-master-practice-test") #démarre la page 
driver.maximize_window()#met en full screen
#démarre le quizz
start_quizz = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class='btn btn-primary btn-quiz-start']"))).click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,400);") #scroll jusqu'en bas de la question

for i in range(40):
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[class='btn btn-primary']"))).click()

complete_quizz = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Complete quiz')]"))).click()
```

then, Im trying with this code to click on each question, get all the informations needed and get back to the Quiz result page, but it always go back to the first question. So it gives me 40 times same question.
it is a list but always gets me the first element ?

(I have just tried to get the question name for now)

```
all_questions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='quiz-answer wrong-answer']")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,3000);") #scroll jusqu'en bas de la question

for q in all_questions:
    click_question = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='quiz-answer wrong-answer']"))).click()
    #time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,400);") #scroll jusqu'en bas de la question
    nom_question = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'question-title text-center')]/h3").text
    print(nom_question)
    #time.sleep(2)
    back_question = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Back to the results')]"))).click()
```

I've tried to replace "driver" by "q" in the elements to be clickable but doesnt work.

Comment: first, try [getting a list of all the questions in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23924280/4935162). when you have that, iterate over it.

Comment: yes, it is what I have done with :  all_questions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='quiz-answer wrong-answer']")

and if I iterate over it I can get the 40 questions, but what I want to do is to get Q/A and correct answers and I can only do it by clicking on each question and go back each time, so I tried to do it  but it only gets back to the first question each time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be a case of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

**I know it's not what you asked for, but anyway:**

By looking at the network requests the browser sends after visiting the page, (f12 -> Network)
you can see one for `/scrum-master.json`.

[image]

So, by visiting [scrum-master.json](http://scrumquiz.org/scrum-master.json) you can download the file and parse it. (for example, with python's [json module](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-json-file-using-python/)).

it seems the `resolution` field contains the indices of the correct answer(s). always the top option, or if it's a multiple choice, top 2.

The order of answers is probably shuffled in the client-side JS.